# Some images will not display on Chrome, Safari, and every mobile browser I have checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://flappyflorent.tk

Only the pipes will not display, hosted on Google Drive. It works fine in Firefox and Opera on desktop, but the pipes will not show on Chrome, IE, or Safari.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Is it advertising script?

Answer (score 0):

Your game behind https, it loaded ssl encrypted,

But you want to load script from http:// protocol which open

Chrome disallows this

**Add:** How @JoshRutherford suggested, yes, put your scripts to google-drive too :)

**Update**:

```
document.write(unescape(
   "%3cscript type='text/javascript' src='" + 
     sa_protocol + 
     "://sa.entireweb.com/sense.js'%3e%3c/script%3e"));
```

**Why** are you doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Check your console:

`[blocked] The page at 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B8Uea9vRbSh-UGtqUzJaTy1OQUk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://sa.entireweb.com/sense.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

Looks like you'll need a certificate for your site, or what I would suggest, just host the images on your server.